# not able to kill snmpd process in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, net-snmp, kill-process

Trying to Kill snmpd process i MAC OSX not able to do, after every Kill it restart again Automatically, not sure who is starting the process again and again, using MAC OSX operation system

```
bash$ ps ax |grep snmpd
22214   ??  Ss     0:00.10 /usr/libexec/snmpd -f
22224 s001  R+     0:00.00 grep snmpd
```

Kiling the Process_Id

```
bash$ sudo kill -9 22214
```

after killing the prcoess again snmpd process is Up

```
bash$ ps ax |grep snmpd
22231   ??  Ss     0:00.08 /usr/libexec/snmpd -f
22234 s001  S+     0:00.00 grep snmpd
```

I tried this so many times not able to Kill the snmpd process,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research Work i got the answer, iN MAC the snmpd started using **launchctl** unloading it has resolved the Issue

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.net-snmp.snmpd.plist
```

after executing this command the snmpd process is get stopped